# How to parse the below mentioned php file using JSON parsing in android

Tags: php, android, json

```
{
    "category": [
        [
            "Item 1"
        ],
        [
            "Item 2"
        ],
        [
            "Item 3"
        ],
        [
            "Item 4"
        ],
        [
            "Item 5"
        ]
    ]
}
```

How to parse this kind of data using JSON Parsing? Items can be added to category in future.
I am new to JSON parsing. So please explain me in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

try{
   JSONArray category = new JSONObject (jsonRespone).getJSONArray("category");
   for (int i=0;i<category.length();i++){
        System.out.println(i+" Value Is :"+category.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
   }
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```